# Spring Batch Bean Scope to convert Legacy Application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, corba

We have a legacy normal java application with below architectural flow

Facade ----> Corba remote IIOP Connection --> ServiceCommands

Above architecture we wants to convert as SpringBeans(Spring Boot) and call from MVCController and expose as RESTAPI

MVCController ---> Facade -->Corba Connection -->ServiceCommands

Please advise what is the Bean scope to be used for each layer and best architecture to be followed

1. Facade class Bean - Scope value="session"
2. CorbaConnection Class bean Scope value="session"
3. ServiceClass bean Scope value="singleton"

Comment: Why would it need to be anything other then singleton? Do they keep state? If not use the default.

Comment: CorbaConnection commit is against each session and maintain connection state . Facade  class can be annotate as singleton as it not maintain state.

Comment: Which session? Corba session != http session or unless something else happen. The fact that you introduce a controller/web API shouldn't influence the facade-corba-commands stuff.

Comment: Its Corba Session. We need to pool corba connection some how to avoid delay of each http request because establishing connection will take time. But if we maintain state corba session commit have issue on concurrency. Any idea how we can create a corba connection pool like hikari connection pool.

Comment: CORBA is too long ago. But you could try using commons-pool (as a generic object pool) to pool the corba connections/sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have solved the issue by created a Corba connection Pool and make each connection from the pool is a Spring bean with scope "Session". Every session request to corba will be in Proxy mode and commit when the @service finishes. All the properties of pools has been added to maintain idle time and re-connection and return back to the pool after the service finishes. Service and Facade remains singleton bean. Thanks team for the support again to provide idea hints from your experiences.